# try to align images right next to a sidebar

Tags: html, css, layout

[this the image I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqR3.jpg)
I'm trying to place the two(2) stacked images right next to each other and also make the whole three(3) images to also align right next to the sidebar tables like in the above image, but each time I try it always goes below the sidebar table. I have tried using flexbox but it doesn't work maybe I don't know it very much. please if anyone can help. Thank you

```
<div class="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="cat">Categories</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Electronics</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Clothing</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Music & Equipment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Footwear</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Software Products</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Computer Hardware</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Mobile Phones</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Laptops</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Furniture</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Beauty Products</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Computer Accessories</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="holder">
    <div class="lone-image"> </div>
    <div class="stacked-image">
        <div class="canon"></div>
        <div class="dell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.table {
    display: flex;
    flex - flow: column;
    border: 1px solid #999696;
    width: 25%;
    height: 60%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table, th, td{
    border-bottom:1px solid black; 
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cat{
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 107);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.holder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.lone-image{
    background-image: url(xii.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 35%;
    height: 410px;
}
.stacked-image{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 4px;
}
.canon{
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(canon.jpg);
    width: 65%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.dell{
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(dell.jpg);
    width: 65%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this.
You can play around with width's and other styling but this should give you the basic idea.

Also, using tables is a bad practice as they offer no responsiveness.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="1table">
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th class="cat">Categories</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Electronics</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Clothing</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Music & Equipment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Footwear</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Software Products</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Computer Hardware</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Mobile Phones</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Laptops</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Furniture</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Beauty Products</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Computer Accessories</th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/JeXUv8x.png" style="height:290px"></td>
            <td colspan="2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/4girMKd.png" style="height:140px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/4girMKd.png" style="height:140px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="lone-image"> </div>
    <div class="stacked-image">
      <div class="canon"></div>
      <div class="dell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I think their was some error in your `width` & `height` selection for each `div`. I changed that and removed a little bit of extra `flex` properties and thats it Just tell me you want something like this.

**Proposed code**

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:60%;
}
.table{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  border: 1px solid #999696;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table, th, td{
  border-bottom:1px solid black; 
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cat{
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 107);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.holder{
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.lone-image{
  background:blue;
  width:60%;
  height: 100%;
}
.stacked-image{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
}
.canon{
  width: 100%;
  background:green;
  height:50%;
}
.dell{
  background:red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="cat"> Categories</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Electronics</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Clothing</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Music & Equipment</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Footwear</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Software Products</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Computer Hardware</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Mobile Phones</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Laptops</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Furniture</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Beauty Products</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Computer Accessories</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="lone-image">
    </div>
    <div class="stacked-image">
      <div class="canon"></div>
      <div class="dell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You were heading in the right direction I know `flexboxes` are really cool but they do take a little while to hang on.

**Do tell me whether I was of any Help :)**

Comment: thank you very much but there is one slight issue. i want the lone image and the stacked images to be spaced out from each other. should using ,argin be a good practise

Comment: I suggest using `padding` instead of `margin` as margin will add space outside the div thus increasing the desired `height & width`.